# kendo-card tag not formatting a card on angular app

Tags: css, kendo-ui, angular9

Looking for help to troubleshoot this.

When I try to create a card on the UI using kendo, it works on stackblitz:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/5zvomp--run?file=app/app.component.ts

[image]

but when trying to create in my angular app, it doesnt show up properly. There are no errors in the console and `import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';` is also there.

[image]

html template:

```html
<kendo-card class="user-card">
  <kendo-card-header class="k-hbox">
    <div>
        <h1 kendoCardTitle>Turtle</h1>
        <p kendoCardSubtitle>Turtle is a small animal</p>
    </div>
  </kendo-card-header>  
</kendo-card>
```

angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as faEllipsisH from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons/faEllipsisH';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-card',
  templateUrl: './user-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-card.component.css']
})
export class UserCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public card: any;

  public faEllipsisH = faEllipsisH;
  public constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I was able to replicate this was if you did not import the Kendo-UI stylesheet.

Take a look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnudiu?file=index.html

If you uncomment out the commented line in index.html, you get the properly styled card. For more information on how to include the styling and themes, visit this documentation: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/#toc-including-themes-by-using-precompiled-css